# Can I capture motion-trails with a point-and-shoot camera?

Tags: point-and-shoot, sports, motion-blur

Is it possible to capture motion trails (like throwing a ball or running) using a camera like the Nikon Coolpix S70?

If so, how do I do it?

Comment: What about making it explicit on the question that this is about the Coolpix S70? Or maybe even on the tags as this may be helpful for other point and shoot cameras.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/when-should-you-use-a-normal-flash-vs-a-second-curtain-flash and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/566/what-is-second-curtain-or-rear-curtain-technique for technique on using flash to freeze motion with a trail behind. Probably not with _this_ camera, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to a lack of a manual or shutter priority mode on the S70, it may be difficult to capture motion in the way you describe.

If there are no 'scene' modes available that provide a long shutter speed your best bet may be to mount the camera on a tripod, disable the flash & set the ISO to its lowest (if possible) then shoot in a low light situation. This will hopefully force the camera into a long enough shutter speed to create some form of motion trail.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a Canon point & shoot you could install [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) on it and manually adjust the shutter speed.  I don't think there is anything similar for Nikon cameras, unfortunately.