# Why can't I fire the built-in flash on my Lumix GH4?

Tags: flash, popup-flash, panasonic-lumix

The manual says that I can use the built-in flash in intelligent auto mode, but when I pop it up it stays off. When I go to the menu, flash is grayed out and I can't do anything with it there. I have tried everything I can think of. Any suggestions??

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is shutter speed almost always too long with my Panasonic Lumux GH4 in iA mode?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/72693/11924) (especially @mattdm's answer)

Comment: Relevant to question: What reason are you wanting flash in this instance?  Is it too dark?  Too much motion blur?  What settings does the camera tend to choose when you do this eg shutter speed?

Comment: From manual: _In the following cases, the flash is fixed to forced flash off: 1. When recording motion pictures 2. When [Electronic Shutter] is set to [ON] 3. When [HDR] is set to [ON] 4. When [Silent Mode] is set to [ON]_

Answer (score 1):

In short, this mode tends to assume you do not want to take flash photos, but use the flash only as fill light such as when there is strong backlight and you need to see a darker subject in front.

The mode is "intelligent" in the sense that it doesn't just use simple arithmetic to determine what settings to use and whether to use flash, but tries to analyze the content of the live image data it's getting to see what you are photographing and make decisions based on that.

Thus this mode only uses flash when it believes it will enhance picture quality.

If the flash doesn't fire, but the picture looks OK, then there is no problem and it's working as intended.

If the flash doesn't fire, but the picture exposure was too long causing blur, you need to choose a different mode where you have full control over whether the flash is on or off and you can force it on.

Comment: Have you set the camera to "silent" mode(i.e. no shutter sound) as this also disables the flash!