# Why doesn't "Ai" mode set the proper flash speed?

Tags: hotshoe-flash, panasonic-lumix

After having bought an used Flash (Metz AF 51-1), I "played with it", checking flash functions with my Panasonic DMC GH-3.

Everything seemed to work fine, except in "Ai" (fully automatic) mode:
All other modes set the shutter speed to 1/60, but Ai mode does not.
(In case it matters: the screen was just some in-door scene with no faces to be detected)
When actually taking a shot, the flash fired, but the shutter speed was something like 1.3 seconds, so without a tripod the image is unusable.

In contrast "P" (Program mode) sets the proper shutter speed, just as "A" (Aperture) mode does.

I don't understand.
Is there a setting that prevents setting the proper shutter speed?

It seems the GH-4 still has this problem ([Why is shutter speed almost always too long with my Panasonic Lumux GH4 in iA mode?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/72693/82107)).

Comment: As per the question you've linked, Ai mode is doing exactly what it is designed to do: using the flash as a fill light, not a main light. This isn't a "problem", just a different design decision.

Comment: What surprises me is that the "Ai"-mode is the default for "dummies", i.e.: the expectation is that it does "everything right" automatically. However in low-light situations the results aren't pleasing, most likely. Also (for the GH-3 at least) there is a menu setting for the "fill-in flash" that seems to be unavailable when "Ai"-mode is selected. Yes, some hings are rather odd for the Lumix series.

Comment: I suspect the thinking is that if you're putting on an external flash, you know what you're doing and are out of "dummies" mode.

Comment: So it seems I'll have to measure the power instead of asking. But honestly: What is the advantage of multiple groups of wireless flashlights when a collection of slave flashlights in "auto/computer" mode (measuring the light being reflected) would probably do a better job?