# When would I use rear curtain instead of front curtain sync?

Tags: flash, second-curtain

What are examples of circumstances where rear curtain sync would be preferable to front curtain sync flash?

Comment: Hey, we have a lot of good answers to many of these questions already. They're not bad questions, but maybe you could spend a little time looking before asking? If there's something in an existing question or answer you don't understand, feel free to as a new followup question referring to that one.

Comment: is rear curtain technique 2nd and front curtain the first?

Comment: For that, see [What is second-curtain or rear-curtain technique?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/566/what-is-second-curtain-or-rear-curtain-technique) :) But in short, yes, those are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Second curtain sync is used when you want to get natural motion where light trails lead to an image as opposed to leading away from it.  Normally a flash will go off at the start of a shutter (which is normally longer than the time the flash is active.)  This results in a heavily exposed image followed by a trail of light.  Second curtain reverses this by making the flash go off at the end so you get a trail of light leading to the more heavily exposed moment of time.

Comment: I think you may have it the wrong way around.  With a normal flash, the trails will be *in front of* a moving object and with a rear curtain flash, they'll be *behind*.  If that's what you meant, then sorry but I misunderstood.

Comment: @thomasrutter - yes, that is what I meant.  Second curtain, the light trails lead to the image (ie, they look like the object is moving in the direction it is actually moving).